# Питание от usb разьема

Tags: usb

Добрый вечер всем! есть такая проблема- внешний жесткий диск и айфон при подключении к компу не берут от usb разьема питание, оба устройства работают нормально - жесткий диск работает на другом компе, айфон тоже заряжается от других компов а в этом компе флешки работают нормально. из за чего это может так происходить? если из за бп то как проверить? или если в настройках самого usb как посмотреть? Спасибо всем заранее!

Answer (score 1):

какая операционка?
1) Например, если смотреть в Винде (Корневой USB концетратор) то там говорится, что данное устройство может использовать 500 мА.
2) Попробуйте протестировать для диска кабель с двумя разъемами (для многих винтов и DVD именно такая поставка от производителя).
3) Временно возьмите БП с другого компа и поставьте на свой - сразу все станет ясно.
4) Возможно проблемы у матери (например настройки БИОС`а)

Answer (score 0):

Замерить мультитестером на материнке силу тока, затем на самом интерфейсе USB. Интерфейсы на задней панели имеют аналогичную проблемы? У супруги на стационаре выкидыши на морду приказали долго жить, проверял сначала тыловую панель, затем разъем под выкидыш, затем uSB на морде системника

Comment: Спасибо но все уже решилось после того как я откатил систему

Comment: А и не нужно было её откатывать всю! Похоже, дело было в драйверах. Дежурный режим включился, и не выключился! А в дежурном режиме питание как раз и не подаётся.

Answer (score 0):

*Из комментария пользователя [@AntonReshin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13511/anton-reshin):*

Похоже, дело было в драйверах. Дежурный режим включился, и не выключился. А в дежурном режиме питание как раз и не подаётся.